Computing the difference along the Z axis between two terrain meshes in QGIS
How could I compute the difference along the Z-axis between two terrain meshes in QGIS?
I have two mesh PLY files (different sources) of the same region and I wish I could check their elevation differences:

The vertices of the two meshes are not located as the same (x,y) position as you can see on this 2D picture.
The closest that I found so far is the mesh calculator from the Crayfish plugin from Lutra Consulting:

But I cannot find how (i.e. syntax, variables available in the current scope, etc) to write down a formula here.
